# Execute command determined by output of previous one (i.e., only if there was some output)

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line

Should be fairly simple to answer:

Let's say I wanted to execute a command determined by the output of a previous one in Bash:

```
curl http://website.com 2> /dev/null | grep -i "test" --count | <MY-COMMAND>
```

**What I need:** `<MY-COMMAND>` should only execute if `grep` had some matches (at least 1).

How can I achieve that?

Also, please feel free to add matching tags, I couldn't come up with any

Comment: somebody thinks this belongs on superuser.com (shrug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need the output of grep to be piped to your command? The answer is simpler if you do not. In that case since grep's return code is success only if it finds a match, you can use `&&` or `if`:

```
curl http://website.com 2> /dev/null | grep -q -i "test" && <MY-COMMAND>

if curl http://website.com 2> /dev/null | grep -q -i "test"; then
    <MY-COMMAND>
fi
```

The `&&` operator is a shorthand way of performing an if-else check. It is a short-circuiting operator, which means that the right hand side will only be executed if the left hand side fails.

If you need to pipe the output to your command then you'll need to save the output to a temporary file, test for a match, and then execute your command:

```
if curl http://website.com 2> /dev/null | grep -i "test" > /tmp/grep.txt; then
    <MY-COMMAND> < /tmp/grep.txt
fi
```

Comment: Let me remark that [`ifne`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524530/execute-command-determined-by-output-of-previous-one/5524551#5524551) is an alternative to messing with temporary files.

Answer (score 6):

[`ifne`](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) utility ("run a program if the standard input is not empty") from Jeoy Hess's [moreutils](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/moreutils) package will serve you.

A description of it:

> a command that would run the following
>   command if and only if the standard
>   input is not empty. I often want this
>   in crontabs, as in:
>
> ```
> find . -name core | ifne mail -s "Core files found" root
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
curl http://website.com 2> /dev/null | grep -i "test" && <MY-COMMAND>
```

From the grep man page: "the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise"

The command after && is executed only if the previous command returned exit status 0.

Comment: grep's `-q` options adds some efficiency

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://www.google.com 2>/dev/null | grep window -i -c && echo "this is a success"
```